# AWS Simple Queue Service (SQS) visibility timeout - set max retries count?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

We have a queue using amazon SQS that contains messages.

We have multiple workers that reads from that queue, these workers are stateless means they cannot remember how many retries each message has unless we update the message with retries count.

Currently, if a worker fails to process a message, the message will return into the queue after X seconds we set because we don't delete it, we set `VisisiblityTimeout` parameter which means that the message will return to the queue after X set seconds if it was not deleted by the worker.

Is there an option in SQS queue or message settings to create a retries count, so for instance, if the message has returned to the queue more or equal to 3 times, it will get deleted from the queue?

```
public async pollMessage(queueName: string): Promise<QueueMessagePollResponse> {

    const parameters = {
        VisibilityTimeout: this.configService.queueVisibilityTimeoutSec,
        QueueUrl: this.buildQueueUrl(queueName),
    };

    return new Promise<QueueMessagePollResponse>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.sqs.receiveMessage(parameters, (error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                this.logger.error(`Failed polling from queue with error: ${error.message}`);
                reject(error);
            }

            if (!data.Messages) {
                return resolve(null);
            }

            resolve({
                messageDeletionId: data.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle,
                data: data.Messages[0].Body,
            });
        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can use A DLQ (Dead-Letter Queue). Set the redrive policy of SQS
>   to no. of tries you want, like

[image]

More details https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-dead-letter-queue.html